# Which JavaScript Libraries do not rely on a document and navigator object?

Tags: javascript, iphone, titanium

I'm currently looking for some libraries which might help me during iPhone Development using Appcelerator Titanium. I've heard that since version 1.0 it isn't dependant on webkit anymore and it makes app-development more exiting of course, please correct me if i'm wrong.
As many people out there i love Javascript Frameworks such as JQuery and Mootools much, but they were build specifically to do a great job within a browser and most of the functionality is not needed within the environment Titanium now provides (DOM-Manipulation etc).

Is there any other small library of useful functions i can use for development? Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/).  It provides a lot of useful functional-style commands that extend your ability to work with collections, objects, etc.  Very nice, and not DOM-specific at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can get handy AJAX functionality with the [jx](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/jx/) library. It doesn't depend on there being a browser.

Comment: thx, this will come in handy, looks pretty useful for nice and clean ajax-calls